# Using a p:remoteCommand to update a p:dataTable

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2, remotecommand

Given the following XHTML code that has one `<p:inputText>` and a `<p:dataTable>` having only two columns.

```
<p:remoteCommand name="updateTable" update="dataTable"/>

<p:panel id="panel">
    <p:inputText id="txtValue" value="#{testManagedBean.txtValue}"
                 required="true"/>
    <p:message for="txtValue" showSummary="false"/>
    <p:commandButton actionListener="#{testManagedBean.submitAction}"
                     oncomplete="if(!args.validationFailed) {updateTable();}" 
                     update="panel" value="Submit"/>
</p:panel>

<p:panel id="dataTablePanel" header="Data">
    <p:dataTable id="dataTable" var="row" value="#{testManagedBean}"
                 lazy="true"
                 pageLinks="10"
                 editable="true"
                 rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15"
                 rows="10"
                 rowKey="#{row.catId}"
                 editMode="row">

        <p:ajax event="rowEdit" update=":form:panel dataTable"
                listener="#{testManagedBean.onRowEdit}"/>

        <p:column id="id" headerText="Id">
            <h:outputText value="#{row.catId}"/>
        </p:column>

        <p:column id="catName" headerText="Category">
            <p:cellEditor>
                <f:facet name="output">
                    <h:outputText value="#{row.catName}"/>
                </f:facet>
                <f:facet name="input">
                    <p:inputText value="#{row.catName}" label="Category">
                        <f:validateLength minimum="2" maximum="45"/>
                    </p:inputText>
                </f:facet>
            </p:cellEditor>
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="Edit" width="100">
            <p:rowEditor/>
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
</p:panel>
```

When the given `<p:commandButton>` is pressed, the associated listener `submitAction()` is invoked and finally the `<p:dataTable>` is updated by `<p:remoteCommand>` **only if validations succeed**.

After doing this, if a row held by the given `<p:dataTable>` is updated (which in turn, updates `<p:panel id="panel">` via `<p:ajax>` inside `<p:dataTable>`. It is sometimes necessary), the given `<p:inputText>` in `<p:panel id="panel">` causes validation its borders turn red implying violating the associated validation that should **not** happen.

If `<p:remoteCommand>` is removed and the given `<p:commandButton>` is changed like as follows,

```
<p:commandButton actionListener="#{testManagedBean.submitAction}"
                 update="panel dataTable" value="Submit"/>
```

removing `oncomplete="if(!args.validationFailed) {updateTable();}"`

and the `update` attribute is changed from `update="panel"` to `update="panel dataTable"` then, the `<p:inputText>` does not cause validations, when a row in `<p:dataTable>` is updated.

How to prevent `<p:inputText>` from performing validations, when a row in `<p:dataTable>` is updated using `<p:ajax>` which, in turn updates `<p:panel>` holding the `<p:inputText>` in question?

`<p:remoteCommand>` itself in this case, cannot be omitted. It is necessary to update `<p:dataTable>` only if no validations are violated. Otherwise, costly business services are executed unnecessarily, even though there are validation error(s).

---

The associated JSF managed bean (though completely unnecessary).

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public final class TestManagedBean extends LazyDataModel<Category> implements Serializable
{
    @EJB
    private final CategoryBeanLocal categoryService = null;
    private String txtValue;  //Getter and setter.
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public List<Category> load(int first, int pageSize, List<SortMeta> multiSortMeta, Map<String, Object> filters) {
        setRowCount(categoryService.rowCount().intValue());
        return categoryService.getList(first, pageSize, multiSortMeta, filters);
    }

    public void submitAction() {
        System.out.println("txtValue : " + txtValue);
        txtValue = null;
    }

    public void onRowEdit(RowEditEvent event) {
        System.out.println("onRowEdit() called.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *After doing this, if a row held by the given `<p:dataTable>` is updated (which in turn, updates `<p:panel id="panel">` via `<p:ajax>` inside `<p:dataTable>`. It is sometimes necessary), the given `<p:inputText>` in `<p:panel id="panel">` causes validation its borders turn red implying violating the associated validation that should **not** happen.*

This isn't what is happening. If that were true, you'd have seen 3 HTTP requests in the network monitor. But there are only 2 (one from the submit of the panel and one from the `<p:remoteCommand>`).

The cause is the `<p:remoteCommand>` itself. Its `process` attribute [defaults](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/4.0/primefaces-p/remoteCommand.html) to `@all` ("whole view"). You can also confirm this by inspecting the `javax.faces.partial.execute` request parameter in the network monitor. It says `@all`. In other words, the entire form is also submitted/processed, including those empty inputs.

You need to explicitly set it to `@this`:

```
<p:remoteCommand name="updateTable" process="@this" update="dataTable"/>
```

Comment: As usaul, not just an answer but with full technical explanation. Thanks.