# Updating row on complete of <p:ajax event="cellEdit">

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable, tablecelleditor, remotecommand

I want to update cellValue in same row. 
I followed the sugestions of BalusC 
[Updating entire <p:dataTable> on complete of <p:ajax event="cellEdit">](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19548838/updating-entire-pdatatable-on-complete-of-pajax-event-celledit)

After all my code perform 2 Requests. The secound one makes a full page Reload and all data will reseted.

I also tried `<p:remoteCommand name="updateTable"  process="@this" update="kAbnrTbl" />` following this suggestion.
[Using a p:remoteCommand to update a p:dataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23443463/using-a-premotecommand-to-update-a-pdatatable)

Here is JSF Page:

```
<h:form id="kalkEditForm">
        <p:outputPanel id="dropArea">
            <p:remoteCommand name="updateTable" update="kAbnrTbl" />
            <p:dataTable id="kAbnrTbl" value="#{tableBean.data}" var="data" editable="true" editMode="cell">

                <p:ajax event="cellEdit"  listener="#{tableBean.onCellEdit}" oncomplete="updateTable()"/> 

                <p:column headerText="Col1">  
                    <p:cellEditor>
                        <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{data.col1}" /></f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText value="#{data.col1}" /></f:facet>
                    </p:cellEditor> 
                    </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Col2">
                    <h:outputText value="#{data.col2}" />
                </p:column>
           </p:dataTable>   
        </p:outputPanel>
</h:form>
```

And here Bean:

```
    @ManagedBean(name="tableBean")
    @ViewScoped
    public class TableBean {

    public TableBean() {
        RowData entry = new RowData("a1", "b1");
        entries.add(entry);
        entry = new RowData("a2", "b2");
        entries.add(entry);
        entry = new RowData("a3", "b3");
        entries.add(entry);
    }
public class RowData {

    private String col1;
    private String col2;

    public RowData(String col1, String col2) {
        this.col1 = col1;
        this.col2 = col2;
    }

    public String getCol1() {
        return col1;
    }

    public void setCol1(String col1) {
        this.col1 = col1;
    }

    public String getCol2() {
        return col2;
    }

    public void setCol2(String col2) {
        this.col2 = col2;
    }
}

private final ArrayList<RowData> entries = new ArrayList<RowData>();

public List<RowData> getData() {
    return entries;
}

public void onCellEdit(CellEditEvent event) {
    final DataTable dataTable = (DataTable)event.getComponent();
    RowData data = (RowData) dataTable.getRowData();
    data.setCol2("changed");
  }
```

}

I have no idea what is wrong with the code. Why perform `<p:remoteCommand ...` the second Request.

Using:Primface 5.3

Back to the beginning point. If I don't use `<p:remoteCommand name="updateTable" update="kAbnrTbl" />` hack, it works ok but I have to press the **refreshButton**. 
If I use the hack I have 2 Requests and a full page reload. There must be a tiny typo or something that I overlook.

Here the code without the hack.

```
<h:form id="kalkEditForm">
        <p:outputPanel id="dropArea">
            <!-- <p:remoteCommand name="updateTable" update="kAbnrTbl" /> -->
            <p:dataTable id="kAbnrTbl" value="#{tableBean.data}" var="data" editable="true" editMode="cell">
                <p:ajax event="cellEdit"  listener="#{tableBean.onCellEdit}" update="kAbnrTbl"/>
                <!-- <p:ajax event="cellEdit"  listener="#{tableBean.onCellEdit}" oncomplete="updateTable()"/> -->
                <p:column headerText="Col1">
                    <p:cellEditor>
                        <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{data.col1}" /></f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText value="#{data.col1}" /></f:facet>
                    </p:cellEditor>  
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Col2">
                    <h:outputText value="#{data.col2}" />
                </p:column>
           </p:dataTable>   
        </p:outputPanel>
         <p:commandButton id="refreshButton" value="Redisplay" update="kAbnrTbl" />
    </h:form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the note from user3821232, the workaround is to be used instead of "celleditor" "inplace" in conjunction with a standard `<p:ajax..` call.

Here you can see the workaround.

xthml:

```
<h:form id="kalkEditForm">
        <p:outputPanel id="dropArea">
            <p:dataTable id="kAbnrTbl" value="#{tableBean.data}" var="data" editable="true" editMode="cell" rowIndexVar="row">
                <p:column headerText="Col1" id="col1" sortBy="#{data.col1}" sortable="true">
                    <p:inplace>
                        <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{data.col1}" /></f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input">
                            <p:inputText value="#{data.col1}" > 
                                <p:ajax event="blur" process="@this" listener="#{tableBean.updateData(row, 'col1')}" update="kAbnrTbl"/>
                            </p:inputText>  
                        </f:facet>
                    </p:inplace>
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Col2">
                    <h:outputText id="col2" value="#{data.col2}" />
                </p:column>
           </p:dataTable>   
        </p:outputPanel>
    </h:form>
```

Bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name="tableBean")
@ViewScoped
public class TableBean {

private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(TableBean.class);

public TableBean() {
    RowData entry = new RowData("a1", "b1");
    entries.add(entry);
    entry = new RowData("a2", "b2");
    entries.add(entry);
    entry = new RowData("a3", "b3");
    entries.add(entry);
}

public class RowData {
    private String col1;
    private String col2;

    public RowData(String col1, String col2) {
        this.col1 = col1;
        this.col2 = col2;
    }

    public String getCol1() {
        return col1;
    }

    public void setCol1(String col1) {
        this.col1 = col1;
    }

    public String getCol2() {
        return col2;
    }

    public void setCol2(String col2) {
        this.col2 = col2;
    }
}

private final ArrayList<RowData> entries = new ArrayList<RowData>();

public List<RowData> getData() {
    return entries;
}

public void updateData(Integer row, String colName){
    logger.debug(String.format("updateData called row:%d colName %s", row, colName));
    RowData data = getData().get(row);
    data.setCol2("changed");
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I used **event="rowEdit"**, this worked for me.

```
<p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{tableBean.onCellEdit}" oncomplete="updateTable()" />
```

Comment: That is what I want to avoid. I wonder why remoteCommand causes a full page reload.

Comment: Our client don`t like the pencil and don`t want to click 2 times. So cellEdit is prefered. I tried your suggestion but then listener `tableBean.onCellEdit` is not called.

Comment: In another page I used p:inplace to update the cell value.  <br/> `<p:inplace>
 <f:facet name="output">
  <h:outputText value="#{_task.status.label }"/>
 </f:facet>
 <f:facet name="input">
  <h:selectOneMenu hideNoSelectionOption="false"
         value="#{_task.status}"
   <f:selectItems
    value="#{factoryEnum.enumStatusTask}"
           var="_enumStatusTask"
    itemValue="#{_enumStatusTask}" />
   <p:ajax process="@this" onsuccess="filter();" listener="#{monitorController.updateTask(_task)}"/>
  </h:selectOneMenu>
 </f:facet>
</p:inplace>`

Comment: Updating the current cellvalue is not the problem. Display the updated cellvalue in another column is the problem. The table is NOT updating.

Comment: I tried to use <p:cellEditor> and I had problem too. When I used <p:inplace> with <p:ajax> that I succeeded.

Comment: I will give it a try.